# Missing UWP in visual studio 2017 after repair

Tags: visual-studio

I was repaired the visual studio after the uwp template is missing in visual studio 2017 but the existing projects are open and run.but, i not able to create the new uwp applications and add the views in existing uwp application.

how to add uwp template in visual studio 2017. i was checked installer it's checked for installed.

Any one know help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding missing templates with the Visual Studio Installer:

[image: Add templates]